# Get number of physical CPU cores in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

`navigator.hardwareConcurrency` returns the number of logical cores. In my experiments, the performance stops improving if I have more Web Workers than physical cores. Is there a way to get the number of physical cores?

Comment: It looks like it's up to the browser to decide how many cores to report. 
"The browser may, however, choose to report a lower number of logical cores in order to represent more accurately the number of Workers that can run at once, so don't treat this as an absolute measurement of the number of cores in the user's system."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency

Comment: Yeah, in general browsers don't like exposing actual details about the machine they're running on.  It's a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but for anyone else passing by, you could use [WebCPU](https://github.com/darionco/WebCPU).
It estimates the number of physical cores in the client:

```
import {WebCPU} from 'webcpu';

WebCPU.detectCPU().then(result => {
    console.log(`Reported Cores: ${result.reportedCores}`);
    console.log(`Estimated Idle Cores: ${result.estimatedIdleCores}`);
    console.log(`Estimated Physical Cores: ${result.estimatedPhysicalCores}`);
});
```